# Как с помощью htaccess сделать перенаправление на мобильную версию сайта?

Tags: .htaccess

Как с помощью htaccess сделать перенаправление на мобильную версию сайта?
В данном случае интересует как это сделать в Вордпрессе. И есть ли такой сервис на котором можно было бы проверить срабатывает ли перенаправление?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone 
RewriteRule .* http://iphone.example.com/ [R]
```

Копай в сторону user_agent